# Is this Grothendieck trace map an isomorphism?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a commutative ring and let $S := \operatorname{Spec}(A)$. Let

$$ g : Y \to X $$

be a proper, birational morphism of separated schemes of finite type over $S$, where $X$ is affine and smooth over $S$.

Consider the dualising complexes $\omega^\bullet_{Y/S}$ and $\omega^\bullet_{X/S}$ on $Y$ and $X$, respectively. We have the Grothendieck trace map in the derived category of quasi-coherent sheaves on $X$

$$ \operatorname{Tr}_g : Rg_\ast (\omega^\bullet_{Y/S}) \to \omega^\bullet_{X/S} $$

associated with $g$.

**Question:** Under what conditions on $A$ and $Y$ is $\operatorname{Tr}_g$ is an isomorphism?

Is it true, for example, if $Y$ is Gorenstein and $A$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-algebra?

I am particularly interested in the case where $A = \mathbb{Z} / p^n \mathbb{Z}$ for some $n \geq 0$.

Comment: I don't think that's enough. If $Y$ has rational singularities, then yes. If it doesn't then (in general) probably not. I can't write more right now, but I will try to explain in more details later if no one else answers.

Comment: Thanks! All details would be very gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Dear Sandor, any chance that you might be able to provide an example of what might go wrong if $Y$ doesn't have rational singularities?